# SOAP client for AWS Lambda using Python 3.5

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, soap, wsdl, aws-lambda

I am writing a serverless script using AWS Lambda function (runtime Python 3.5) to connect to a SOAP server, get some data, process that data then update some records in storage.

I have written the script on my local machine where I had to install the 'suds' SOAP client. I have it all working correctly, however AWS doesn't have suds installed and i'm not sure how to get it installed or whether I can.

Has anyone tried writing a soap client in aws lambda using python and if so can they give me some suggestions on how to progress further?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

This is really a more general question about packaging dependencies in a Python AWS Lambda function deployment. [This documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) details the process of including your dependencies in your AWS Lambda zip file deployment artifact.